# How to remove leading zero from a number arraylist?

Tags: java, android

In my app there is an `arrayList` which consist of numbers, in the below code, `numbers`  will output an arrayList like this:
`[01, 02, 03, 04, 05 , 06, 07 , 08, 09 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`
The size is variable it may reach up to 100 or more.

So, what I need is to remove the leading zero from [ 01 until 09 ].

So, I want the output to be like this
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6, 7 , 8, 9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`

***Updated***

```
    ArrayList<Model> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Garden e : Flowers) {
        numbers.add(new Model(e.Tulip));
    }
```

Flowers is a larger arraylist, so I only want Tulip from it

***Flowers example***

```
    Flowers= [
    {
        Tulip= "01", 
        Orchid= "orange",
        Hyacinth= "05", }
    {
        Tulip= "02", 
        Orchid= "black",
        Hyacinth= "05", }
    {
        Tulip= "03", 
        Orchid= "blue",
        Hyacinth= "05", }
    ]
```

Comment: Look into `Model.toString()`, those zeros have nothing to do with arrays, lists, or `ArrayList`

Comment: Can you give me the code of your Model. What is e.Flowers?

Comment: those numbers are parsed from an online api , so it has nothing to do with model thanks

Comment: Ok will update asap

Comment: Flowers is larger arraylit , numbers will retrieve only Tulip from it

Comment: I fixed my post can please remove downvote , this is my first post

Comment: can you add the code you have now? the main class ,the class Model, and the class Garden

Comment: Ok I will do it ASAP

Comment: @Ofek I updated the post kindly check it , but the names are different  that was just an example

Comment: If you want help learning java, we can contact via discord and I will help you where you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static removeLeadingZeros(String str)
{
 String regex = "^0+(?!$)";
 str = str.replaceAll(regex, "");
 System.out.println(str);

return str;
}


ArrayList<Model> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for(Garden e : Flowers){
   string leadingNumber  = removeLeadingZeros(Number)  // Pass the number of the for loop )
   numbers.add(new Model(leadingNumber));
}
```

Comment: string leadingNumber  = removeLeadingZeros(e.Tulip)
numbers.add(new Model(leadingNumber));

Comment: you are missing a ';' and a capital S at string leadingNumber

Comment: add `String` after `static`

Comment: (Number) expression expected

Comment: instead of `Number`, you need to put the number you want to fix. also, change the `string` to `String`.

Comment: Thanks ,I changes to capital, but I cannot resolve `Number` still

Comment: I don't know what is the thing you want to fix, i can guess you want to change it to `e.Tulip`

Comment: I think you removed `e.Tulip` from the equation , how to fix that kindly

Comment: Thanks @Ofek for your support!

I sent the update function in the comment!

Comment: I updated my post , kindly check it, I think it is more clear now

Comment: sure, I will answer ASAP

Comment: I updated the post kindly check it , but the names are different that was just an example

Comment: public String removeLeadingZeros(String str)
{
 String regex = "^0+(?!$)";
 str = str.replaceAll(regex, "");
 System.out.println(str);

return str;
}


ArrayList<Model> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for(Garden e : Flowers){
   string leadingNumber  = removeLeadingZeros(e.Tulip);
   numbers.add(new Model(leadingNumber));
}

Comment: Thank you so much sir the updated code worked like a charm, you are a life savor , I appreciate its sir

Comment: Better update the answer with the data that helped them solve the problem. Your answer, as is, is not programmatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
for(Garden e : Flowers)
    numbers.add(removeLeadingZeros(e.Tulip));
```

Comment: your answer is working and I appreciate it sir , but I cannot change the type to Integer, I will have edit my recyceler view which uses the model,

Comment: @codebreaker i edited, its now using the function of Bernard Estephan

Comment: Thank you so much , but but even string is not working , it has to be of model type , Bernard Estephan added a comment that is the correct method , again thank you so much , I appreciate it